# Get a route prefix variable in the abstract base controller

Tags: laravel, routes

So we are building a CMS for a school project and we need to make it dynamic in the way that there are multiple organisations. In the prefix of a group I add a `$gid` variable that represents the ID of this organisation.

```
Route::middleware('auth')->prefix('{$gid}/admin')->group(function()
```

So I also created an abstract base controller that every controller in the admin section will inherit.

```
abstract class BaseAdminController extends Controller
```

What I want now is the `$gid` variable from the route and parse it to the base controller in the constructor.

```
protected $gid;

public function __construct() {
    $this->gid = .....;
}
```

Now I can access this ID everywhere instead of having to parse it to each individual controller and function.

Comment: You can try the `request()` helper to do that: `request()->route('gid')`

Comment: @AkshayKhale problem is that laravel wants me to set `$gid` in every function because otherwise it would be missing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "parse" it in every action but you should keep it because otherwise you wouldn't be able to access the routes' other parameters because the first one is missing and Laravel wouldn't be able to assign the next one's correctly. And you don't need the dollar sign at the start of a parameter.

```
// routes/web.php
                                 // ↓ No dollar sign here
Route::middleware('auth')->prefix('{group}/admin')->group(function() {
    // Routes
});

// In any of your Controllers
use Illuminate\Http\Request:

class SomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function index(Request $request, Group $group) // you might add more parameters here
    {
        // Access your $group model
    }
}
```

If you don't need the group model, don't define the type of the parameter and the related data will not be loaded:

```
public function index(Request $request, $group) // Now $group is just a number
```